# The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I ran this script to connect to MongoDB using mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/curious", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;

const dbLog = (msg) => {
    console.log(`[DATABASE] [SUCCESS] ${msg}`);
}

const dbLogError = (msg) => {
    console.error(`[DATABASE] [ERROR] ${msg}`);
}

db.on("error", dbLogError("Database connection failure"));
db.once("open", () => {
    dbLog("Database connection successful");
})

mongoose.connection.close()
```

I received the following error

```
PS D:\scripts> node .\dbUtils.js
[DATABASE] [ERROR] Database connection failure
events.js:110
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:110:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:347:3)
    at NativeConnection.addListener (events.js:405:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Workspace\curious-backend\scripts\dbUtils.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

What is this error and how can I fix this?

Stackoverflow won't let me post without more text, so, all of you have a great day. These are tough times. Love yourself and take care.

Comment: You are *calling* `dbLogError` and passing the *result* (which is not a function) into `db.on()`. Compare this to `db.once` right below, where you actually pass a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like problem is in `error` listener, as it expecting function. Update:

```
db.on("error", dbLogError("Database connection failure"));
```

to:

```
db.on("error", () => dbLogError("Database connection failure"));
```

and it should work!